# how to activate a function after validate?

Tags: jquery, validation

This is my validate for email_address

```
$().ready(function() {
$('#email_settings').validate({
rules: {
    email_address: { required:true, email:true, minlength:7 }
}
});
});
```

I need to call below query after above validation before submit the page

```
$.post('../get_email_availability.php',
    {eml_ad:$('#email_address').val()},
    function(data){
    if (data=='available'){}
    else{}
    });
```

Comment: Are you using some jQuery validation plugin?

Comment: Just add a `submitHandler` callback function to your validate options. http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate

Comment: better use [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) it has everything you need

Comment: yes i using jquery validation. what i need is, after email validation, check with database for this email address is alredy exist in the database or no. if exist not submit otherwise submitthe form

Comment: thanks mr cbroe.. ur method is also working

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
if($('#email_settings').valid())
{
   $.post(...);
}
else return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had implemented this similar feature.
I used "addMethod" function to achieve this function:
[jQuery.validator.addMethod(name,method[,message])](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod)

It can add a custom validation method. In this case, we need a "email availability" checker which will check the email with database.

You could try this:

```
$.validator.addMethod("checkEmailUsed",function(value,element){
  var result=$.ajax({
      url:"../get_email_availability.php",
      type:"POST",
      async:false,
      data: "eml_ad="+$('#email_address').val()
  }).responseText;
  if(result==="available"){ 
    return true //can be used
  }else{ 
    return false;
  }
},"E-mail is not available.");
```

And don't forget to add this custom vaildation method to email validation rule.

```
$('#email_settings').validate({
  rules: {
    email_address: { required:true, email:true, minlength:7, checkEmailUsed: true }
  }
});
```

I hope this will be helpful for you